# Marketing Cloud: Query failed during execution. Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Every day a file is dropped on an FTP which consists of people with their relationnumbers (relatienummer) and the products (documentnummer) that they have bought. However, the same person can buy multiple products. I have a journey that is only for people that buy 1 specific product in the file and I want to select these people and insert them into a Data Extension in which relation number is the identifier.

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Relatienummer, 
       m.Aanmaakdatum,
       m.Documentnummer
FROM Acquisitie_Campagne_Testrapporten_PROD m
WHERE  Artikelcode = 'DOS006' AND m.Aanmaakdatum = Cast(Dateadd(dd, -1, Getdate())as date)
```

Query failed during execution.

> Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'Acquisitie_Campagne_Main_Contacts_PROD'. The duplicate
>   key value is (0001423---).

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: What is the relatienummer, is that a Customer Number or the unique identifier for a purchase? If its a customer number what happens if someone buys this product twice in different purchases, will that violate the unique constraint?

Comment: Hi Johannes, the relatienummer is the customer number :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you'd use a T-SQL windowing function to de-duplicate the rows.

If your primary key in the target data extension is only `Relatienummer`, then you can partition by that field and order the duplicates by `Aanmaakdatum`.  The `row_number()` numbers them in order.  The where-clause in the outer query picks the first one for each `Relatienummer`.

```
select 
  x.Relatienummer
, x.Aanmaakdatum
, x.Documentnummer
from (
    SELECT 
      m.Relatienummer
    , m.Aanmaakdatum,
    , m.Documentnummer
    , row_number() over (partition by m.Relatienummer order by m.Aanmaakdatum asc) ranking
    FROM Acquisitie_Campagne_Testrapporten_PROD m
    WHERE  
    m.Artikelcode = 'DOS006' 
    and m.Aanmaakdatum >= convert(date,getDate()-1)
    and m.Aanmaakdatum < convert(date,getDate())
) x 
where x.ranking = 1
```

I have a list of fixes for the 4 types of SFMC query errors [**on my blog**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/troubleshooting-queries-sfmc/).

Comment: I think `w.Relatienummer` and `w.Aanmaakdatum` should read `m.Relatienummer` and `m.Aanmaakdatum`

Comment: Fixed the aliases.